# How to add HAproxy on Kafka broker

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, haproxy, kubernetes-ingress

I have Kubernetes setup on 3 nodes. 3 Kafka brokers are running successfully on the cluster. There is a third-party application outside the cluster that is using this Kafka. The third-party application(tool) can only use 1 broker list in its config. The tool is unable to add 3 broker list. All good, but sometimes tool got `notleaderforpartitionexception`.
the tool is not able to switch on another broker.

is it possible to add a proxy layer in Kubernetes which can give HA to the Kafka cluster? Can someone provide me some sample for the proxy layer?

Comment: Even if you only provide one broker as bootstrap server to a client, it should discover the rest of the cluster automatically once connected. Are you sure the exceptions you ae seeing are actually caused by this?

Comment: That application seems to be written wrong if it doesn't support a comma separated list of brokers.